# .NET JsonConverter WriteJson Stackoverflow Exception

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have a custom converter for so I can ignore empty strings but the WriteJson method throws a stackoverflow exception. What's the proper way to write out the value here?

```
internal class StringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var theValue = reader.Value?.ToString();

        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(theValue) ? theValue : null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString()); //stackoverflow error here
            return;
        }

        writer.WriteNull(); //how do I get it to skip the entry?
    }

    public static readonly StringConverter Singleton = new StringConverter();
}
```

Comment: Would `writer.WriteString(...)` make more sense here?

Comment: @Matthew - thanks. WriteValue does the trick.

Comment: You can't use a custom converter to skip writing a value.  Once `WriteJson()` is called the property name is already written.  See: [Custom Json.NET converter should not serialize a property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52671471/3744182).  If you want to omit empty strings from an object, see [Remove empty string properties from json serialized object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41287224/3744182).  In fact this may be a duplicate of those two, agree?

Comment: @dbc I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/53878125/2297041 to skip the empty strings

Comment: @rory - glad that worked!